# tcp server connection times out when data is sent to it

Tags: java, android, tcp, server, client

I'm trying to set up a TCP client-server setup here. I have an android app as the client and a Java server to catch the data. My problem is that the Connection to the server times out before the data is sent I'm assuming.  Like it either never sends or it cant get through. The port is shown in netstat as open and I have even attempted port forwarding but nothing seems to work. Here is the code for the android app  the data is sent via async task.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText el;
Button button;
public final static  String TAG = "PcnoTest";
private static Socket s;
private static ServerSocket ss;
private static InputStreamReader isr;
private  static BufferedReader br;
private static PrintWriter pr;
String message;






@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         el = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
         button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {

            message = el.getText().toString();
            sendData sd = new sendData();
            sd.execute(message);
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data Sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
         });

}

class sendData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {


 @Override
 protected Void doInBackground(String... voids) {

     String message = voids[0];

     try {

         Log.i(TAG,"Attempting to send...");
         s = new Socket("10.0.0.3", 5041);
         pr = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
         pr.write(message);
         pr.flush();
         pr.close();
         s.close();

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }


     return null;
 }



 }
 }
```

and here is the java side.  using NetBeans if that makes a difference somehow.

```
public class Androidserver extends JFrame{

private JPanel contentPane;
private static ServerSocket ss;
private static Socket s;
private static BufferedReader br;
private static InputStreamReader isr;
private static String message;
private static int port = 5041;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                try{
                    Androidserver frame = new Androidserver();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        try{
            while(true){
        ss = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println( "Server is running on port" + port );
        s = ss.accept();
         isr = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
         br = new BufferedReader(isr);
         message = br.readLine();

         System.out.println(message);

        isr.close();
        br.close();
        ss.close();
        s.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    }



public Androidserver(){
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100,100,450,300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(3,3,3,5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblClient = new JLabel("Server");
    lblClient.setBounds(99,34,46,14);
    contentPane.add(lblClient);


}
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you didn't include the relevant code. I noticed

    sendData sd = new sendData();

but that doesn't help much. Is "sendData" a class? It should be capitalized. The problem likely lies in there.

Comment: Did you even scroll to look or just glance

Comment: Sorry, missed the scroll bar. Try separating out your socket code from the rest. That should make it easier to test. What behavior are you seeing? Does it hang or just complete immediately? There is little chance the connection is closing itself. Try waiting for a response on the socket before you start closing things.

Comment: The `ServerSocket` should be created before the accept loop, and not closed in it. You must be getting connect exceptions you haven't told us about.

Comment: The server just hangs.  I was working on it after I posted this. it never accepts the connection just floats

Comment: And yes there is a Time out execption. I stated It. When I asked my question